# Can't enable the Google Calendar API

Tags: ios, google-api, google-calendar-api

I use `Google API` to create `iOS app`:

https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/ios?ver=swift

But when I "Click the Enable the Google Calendar API button." I got the `error 404` "The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know.".

How can I enable `Google Calendar API` ?

Answer (score 0):

[Error 404](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#404_not_found) means that:

> The specified resource was not found. This can happen in several
>   cases. Here are some examples:
>
> - when the requested resource (with the provided ID) has never existed
> - when accessing a calendar that the user can not access
>
> Suggested action: Use [exponential backoff](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/errors#exponential-backoff).